# How to Quickly Consolidate Duplicate Information

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working on a project where I need to merge many duplicates. The problem is that they also have unique identifiers that I need to consolidate into one cell. Specifically, these are polling locations. Some polling locations have multiple election districts assigned to them (meaning people who live in those districts would vote there) while others only have one district assigned. Here is an example of what those observations would look like:

```
    Location Name            |Precinct ID
[1] Place 1                  | 12345
[2] Place 1                  |45678
[3] Place 2                  |78945
```

And this is how I would like it to look at the end

```
   Location Name             |Precinct ID
[1] Place 1                  |12345, 45678
[2] Place 2                  |78945
```

Does anyone know what package or function I should use to merge duplicates in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to use `dplyr:summarise()` to `paste` precinct IDs by location:

```
df %>%
  summarize(Precinct_ID = paste(Precinct_ID, collapse = ", "), 
         .by = Location)

#    Location  Precinct_ID
# 1  Place 1 12345, 45678
# 2  Place 2        78945
```

A base R equivalent would be:

```
aggregate(Precinct_ID ~ Location, 
          data = df, 
          FUN  = \(x) paste(x, collapse = ", "))

#   Location  Precinct_ID
# 1  Place 1 12345, 45678
# 2  Place 2        78945
```

Data

```
df <- read.table(text = "Location             Precinct_ID
'Place 1'                   12345
'Place 1'                  45678
'Place 2'                  78945", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `list` or `c` in `aggregate`.

```
> (res <- aggregate(Precinct_ID ~ Location, df, c))
  Location  Precinct_ID
1  Place 1 12345, 45678
2  Place 2        78945
```

Looks similar. With the advantage that we can still easily access information,

```
> res[1, 2][[1]][2]
[1] 45678
```

because

```
> str(res)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Location   : chr  "Place 1" "Place 2"
 $ Precinct_ID:List of 2
  ..$ : int  12345 45678
  ..$ : int 78945
```

Alternatively, if that's not wanted we can coerce `toString`.

```
> aggregate(Precinct_ID ~ Location, df, toString)
  Location  Precinct_ID
1  Place 1 12345, 45678
2  Place 2        78945
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Location = c("Place 1", "Place 1", "Place 2"), 
    Precinct_ID = c(12345L, 45678L, 78945L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```